# Missing app transfer link for new app in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have created a new app in iTunes Connect and filled in the basic details such as description, screen shot, etc.

After I created the app I can see the ‘View in App Store’ link but not ‘App Transfer’ link.

When is the app transfer link enabled?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of criteria for app transfer to be available, but since you mention that you've created a new app and only filled in the details, it's likely the app hasn't met this restriction:

> - The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store.

[App transfer criteria - iTunes Connect Developer Help](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devaf27784ff)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72435/discussion-between-venka-tesh-user5397700-and-grgarside).